# lazy loading error when working with modals components

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

hello i'm trying use to use lazy loading with modal component, so i have a shared components module like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AddNoteComponent,
    EditNoteComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    AddNoteComponent,
    EditNoteComponent
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

i want to use them in notes.ts page, so i imported the componentsModule class to the notes.module.ts like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NotesPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(NotesPage),
    ComponentsModule,
  ],
})
export class NotesPageModule {}
```

so in my notes.ts this function should work

```
addNoteModal() {
  let noteModal = this.modalCtrl.create('AddNoteComponent', {
    'mid': this.module.key
  });
  noteModal.present();
}
```

this should work pefectly while i use lazy loading,

but ionic tells me that :

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: AddNoteComponent

here is my environment : 
*Ionic Framework: 3.9.2 

Ionic App Scripts: 3.1.2 

Angular Core: 5.0.1 

Angular Compiler CLI: 5.0.1 

Node: 8.4.0 

OS Platform: Windows 10 

Navigator Platform: Win32 

User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Mobile Safari/537.36*

Comment: I think your `AddNoteComponent` should be a page, i.e. it should have a `@IonicPage()` decorator.

Comment: yeah but i want it to be just a component, it's in the components folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use *a page* as a modal, not *a regular component*. So if you want to create a modal with the content of the `AddNoteComponent`, you'll need to create a new page (including the `@IonicPage()` decorator so it could be lazy-loaded) that imports that component, and then use *that page* as the modal.

So this would be the page:

```
// Angular
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// Ionic
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-add-note',
    templateUrl: 'add-note.html'
})
export class AddNotePage {

    constructor() { }

    // ...

}
```

This would be the module of the page:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AddNotePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(AddNotePage),
    ComponentsModule,
    // ...
  ],
})
export class AddNotePageModule {}
```

And this is how you'll use that page:

```
addNoteModal() {
  let noteModal = this.modalCtrl.create('AddNotePage', {
    'mid': this.module.key
  });
  noteModal.present();
}
```

Comment: but before i do lazy loading it was working fine, is it possible to work with the components

Comment: It probably worked before since not lazy-loaded pages *are just components* but I'm afraid that's not the way it should be done in Ionic when using lazy-loaded pages.

Comment: Glad to help @MohamedBOUKHLIF :)